# How can I use filter on listview when type something on Edittext in Android

Tags: java, android, listview, mobile, android-edittext

I want to find out specify user by edittext. However the edittext is the first row of the ListView. 
How can I make this possible?

```
 public class ChatFragment extends Fragment {
    private ListView chatListView;
    private List<ChatItem> items;
    private ChatAdapter chatAdapter;

    public static ChatFragment newInstance(){
        ChatFragment fragment = new ChatFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_fragment, container, false);
        chatListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.chatListView);
        setupChatList();
        chatListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        return view;
    }

    public void setupChatList(){
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new ChatItem(1, "","","",""));
        items.add(new ChatItem(2 ,"layer1", "Chloe Grace Moretz", "Approved your see post request!", "4 mins"));
        items.add(new ChatItem(3 ,"layer2", "Robert Downey", "ok!", "16:19"));
        items.add(new ChatItem(4 ,"layer3", "Amanda Crew", "haha", "19:01"));
        items.add(new ChatItem(5 ,"layer4", "Noah Urrea", "Good choice ~ man", "Yesterday"));
        items.add(new ChatItem(6 ,"layer5", "Blake Rayne", "Jason Papadopoulos I think", "Sunday"));
        chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(getContext(), items);
        chatListView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
    }

    public void remove(){
        chatAdapter.remove(items.get(1));
    }
}
```

My Adapter is below:

```
  public class ChatAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ChatItem> {
    private List<ChatItem> items;
    private List<ChatItem> filteredData = null;
    private TextView chatNameTxt;
    private TextView msgTxt;
    private TextView msgTimeTxt;
    private ImageView chatImg;
    private ImageView chatMoreImg;
    private Context context;
    private ItemFilter filter = new ItemFilter();
    private EditText findChat;

    public ChatAdapter(Context context, List<ChatItem> items){
        super(context, -1, items);
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (position==0){
            View item0 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_list_view_item0, parent, false);
            findChat = (EditText)item0.findViewById(R.id.findChat);
            findChat.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    ChatFragment chatFragment = new ChatFragment();
                    chatFragment.remove();
                }
            });
            return item0;
        }else {
            View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_list_view, parent, false);
            chatNameTxt = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.chatNameTxt);
            msgTxt = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.msgTxt);
            msgTimeTxt = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.msgTimeTxt);
            chatImg = (ImageView)item.findViewById(R.id.chatImg);
            chatMoreImg = (ImageView)item.findViewById(R.id.chatMoreImg);

            ChatItem friendItem = items.get(position);
            String chatName = friendItem.getUserNmae();
            String msg = friendItem.getLastMsg();
            String msgTime = friendItem.getLastMsgTime();
            String userImg = friendItem.getUserImageName();

            chatImg.setImageResource(context.getResources().getIdentifier(userImg, "drawable", context.getPackageName()));
            chatNameTxt.setText(chatName);
            msgTxt.setText(msg);
            msgTimeTxt.setText(msgTime);

            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: refer this http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/ or http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-adding-search-functionality-to-listview/

Comment: Would like to know what you have done !!!!

Comment: Questions seeking help must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

To `Filter` `ListView` when typing on `EditText` you have follow below way.

1. Add `TextWatcher` to `EditText#addTextChangedListener`
2. In  `onTextChanged` add or remove items from your `ListView`'s adapter. If you are subclassing `ArrayAdapter` it would have `add` and `remove` methods
3. If you are subclassing `BaseAdapter` then make `BaseAdapter implements Filterable`.

> Note : step 2 : is for `ArrayAdapter` and Step 3 : is for
>   `BaseAdapter`.

Comment: It make sense. So do you thing that I don't need to extends Filter?

Comment: @YunyuenChan see here is simple Example you will understand http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-edittext-filter.html also make your `Adapter extends baseAdapter implements Filterable`.

Comment: OK. I try this now.

Comment: @YunyuenChan post your code and also logcat `crash` here.

Comment: it crash at remove().

Comment: @YunyuenChan what is the crash.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: @YunyuenChan you are doing it wrong way.and also you can not use any `Filter`.

Comment: Why? I have tried that calling EditText on ChatFragment but it cannot find EditText.

Comment: it contain notifyDataSetChanged(); Once it run, the first row which contain edittext will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your adapter **[Filterable](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html)**. It will update listview's values automatically.

*I will write the tutorial here tomorrow and keep the link to credit the author.*

Comment: it used notifyDataSetChanged();
Once this run, it will clean the first row so the EditText will be removed.

Comment: I hope that when user scroll down, the search EditText will go up. So I make this first row of the ListView is an EditText.

Comment: Ok. I understand your needs. You could then put a LinearLayout with vertical orientation into a scrollview. It will contains the EditText and the listview

Answer (score 0):

no need to create extra filter class . you just keep string from TextWatcher then check that string with your list view data using contain method

```
searchforcategory.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            getAllCetegory(charSequence.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {



        }
    });
```

now just check that string with your data

```
 for(int i=0;i<response.body().getDataList().size();i++){

                    if(response.body().getDataList().get(i).getName().contains(checkString)){


                        productDataLists.add(response.body().getDataList().get(i));

                    }


                }
```